# Is it possible to remove a custom option group from RDS in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

From the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithOptionGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithOptionGroups.Delete), it can be deleted if it's not associated to any snapshot or db instance.

But now due to an `aws provider` version upgrade for terraform, the [AWS RDS Terraform module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws/latest) changes something for option group in AWS.

It added a new one and want to delete the old one. The old one is using and is associating with many snapshots so can't been deleted.
After finish run the `terraform apply`, check AWS found both the new one and old one exist. On the DB instance modify page found the default choosed option group is the new one.

Now use terraform, can't find a way to remove one of them. And the task always tried to delete the old option group(how to avoid it?).

For the current situation, is it possible to delete the new option group from AWS?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122607/terraform-rds-option-group-being-replaced), it said `custom option group defined in Terraform`. But I didn't found which key name it is.

When upgrade the aws provider version from TF, the db operation was used module

```
module "db" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
  version = "~> 2.0"
  ...

}
```

Where can remove the custom option group by TF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this module you would need to set the following:

> create_db_option_group = false

and then you would create your own option group using terraform `Resource: aws_db_option_group`. Once, you have that in place, you can pass following argument into your module:

> option_group_name = aws_db_option_group.custom_name.id

Comment: Thank you. If already created an another option group with this module in AWS, how to revert? I want to continue to use the old option group and delete the new one created by terraform. Is it possible?